# How can I use IndexOf to pick a specific Character when there are more than one of them?

Tags: c#, string, substring, indexof

How can I use IndexOf with SubString to pick a specific Character when there are more than one of them? Here's my issue. I want to take the path "C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Temp\" and remove the "Temp\" part. Leaving just "C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\" I have solved my problem with the code below but this assumes that the "Temp" folder is actually called "Temp". Is there a better way? Thanks

```
if (Path.GetTempPath() != null) // Is it there?{
tempDir = Path.GetTempPath(); //Make a string out of it.
int iLastPos = tempDir.LastIndexOf(@"\");
if (Directory.Exists(tempDir) && iLastPos > tempDir.IndexOf(@"\"))
{
    // Take the position of the last "/" and subtract 4.
    // 4 is the lenghth of the word "temp".
    tempDir = tempDir.Substring(0, iLastPos - 4);
}}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to trim off the last sub-directory in a path regardless of if it's temp or not?

Comment: Yes, its going to be either TEMP or possibly TMP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The better way is to use [`Directory.GetParent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) or [`DirectoryInfo.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\Jim\AppData\Local\Temp\";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        DirectoryInfo parent = dir.Parent;
        Console.WriteLine(parent.FullName);
    }    
}
```

(Note that `Directory.GetParent(path)` just gives you the Temp directory, as it doesn't understand that the path is already meant to be a directory.)

If you really wanted to use `LastIndexOf` though, use [the overload which allows you to specify the start location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tw91fa3.aspx).

Comment: @CAbbott: I was getting there :)

Comment: @Neal: I know the link, I was just prodding Mr. Skeet to include one in his post.

Comment: Nope, didn't need to use LastIndexOf at all. It was just readily available in my SMALL list of tools I keep in my head. I wasn't aware of GetParent. This works perfectly for me and is MUCH more elegant. Thank you so much!

Comment: @CAbbott: For next time, feel very free to add the links yourself. I promise not to bite :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just handle this directly using the System classes?

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolder(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answerers have shown the best way to accomplish your goal. In the interest of expanding your knowledge further, I suggest that you look at regular expressions for your string matching and replacement needs, in general.

I spent the first couple of years of my self-taught programming career doing the most convoluted string manipulation imaginable before I realized that someone else had already solved all these problems, and I picked up a copy of [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124). I strongly recommend it.

One way to strip off the last directory is with the following regular expression:

```
tempDir = Regex.Match(tempDir, @".*(?=\\[^\\]+)\\?").Value;
```

It may look cryptic, but this will actually remove the last item from the path, regardless of its name, and regardless of whether there is another `\` at the end.

Comment: Thank you Jay. I'll have to check that book out. I've been meaning to look into Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DirectoryInfo class.

```
DirectoryInfo tempDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetTempPath());            
DirectoryInfo tempDirectoryParent = tempDirectory.Parent;
```